# error : package com.google.android.gms.auth does not exist in ant release in cordova app

Tags: cordova-plugins

I installed cordova-plugin-googleplus plugin to login using google. After installing I run "cordova build andriod" in CLI, it was successful and apk file works fine for google login. Then for releasing the app I run "ant release" in platforms/android folder in CLI, then build failed with errors like " package com.google.android.gms.auth does not exist import com.google.android.gms.auth". Please give me the solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/252

Replace

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:+" />
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+" />
```

with

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.2" />
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.2" />
```

in both plugin.xml as well as platforms/android/project.properties. In my case if I replace only plugin.xml then build.gradle was getting overridden with project.properties content and + version was being used instead of specific version